# docker minio/mc not create bucket

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, minio

```
minio:
        image: "minio/minio"
        container_name: myminio
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        environment:
            - "MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE"
            - "MINIO_SECRET_KEY=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY"
        restart: always
        command: server /data
    mc:
        image: minio/mc
        container_name: mc
        depends_on:
            - minio
        entrypoint: >
          /bin/sh -c "
          /mc host rm local
          /mc config host add local http://minio:9000 AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY;
          /mc mb local/somebucketname1;
          /mc policy set public local/somebucketname1;
          "
```

its my docker-compose.yml file , But when i docker-compose up but i see not any bucket create. Whats the problem I try hole day but not found any error

Comment: How did you get past this issue? I'm having the same one.

Comment: show me your compose file then i return you the solution

Answer (score 1):

http://minio:9000 is reacheable for the mc container?

I use http://minio-container:9000 and healthcheck condition (docker-compose version 1.29.2+
).

docker-compose.yml

```
  minio-service:
    image: minio/minio
    container_name: minio-container
    command: server /data
    command: server /data --console-address ":9001"
    ports: 
      - '9000:9000'
      - '9001:9001'
    volumes: 
      - ./storage:/data
    environment:
      - "MINIO_ROOT_USER=minio"
      - "MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=minio123"
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3
  
  mc-service:
    image: minio/mc
    depends_on:
      minio-service:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: on-failure
    entrypoint: >
      /bin/sh -c "
      /usr/bin/mc alias set myminio http://minio-container:9000 minio minio123;
      /usr/bin/mc mb myminio/mybucket;
      /usr/bin/mc policy set public myminio/mybucket;
      "
    networks:
      - mynetwork
```

Comment: For the latest `minio` release (`quay.io/minio/mc:RELEASE.2022-12-13T00-23-28Z`) you should use `mc anonymous set public myminio/mybucket` instead of `mc policy set public myminio/mybucket`